# Is there a workable wallet program for Ubuntu 12?

Tags: software-recommendation, kwallet

I read Kwallet will not load in Ubuntu 12
Is there another wallet program or a work-around?

Comment: Have you tried running Kwallet? As far as I can tell it should be installable from the Software Centre.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for a password manager?  If that is the case look at **KeepassX**.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Good choice, it works on Windows as well and uses the same database so it is perfect to store on Dropbox (or Ubuntu One).

Answer (score 0):

You can install "Pasaffe". It is designed for GNOME and this acts as a password manager where you can save username,password, URLs and few other fields.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mdeslaur/pasaffe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pasaffe
```